# Adding share button to LibGDX for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, libgdx

I am trying to add a button which when pressed shares the high score of the user to the chosen app (facebook, twitter, messaging etc...)

I have been searching online and I just could not find a clear tutorial on how to do this. It may be because I am not so familiar with the terms such as bindings etc.. so I cannot understand these advanced tutorials. Can anyone explain clearly how I could do this?

Thanks!

p.s it would be great for the share button to work for both android and iOS

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook, check out [gdx-facebook](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook).
It's a cool project that integrates `libgdx` with Facebook's API. I discovered it recently, and so far so good.

Please note: There seems to be some `gradle` issues with this project when using **Eclipse IDE**. I've been using it with **Android Studio**, and it's working fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you, that looks great.

Sorry, I am new to this, but how do I use it? How can I put that into my project, I haven't used github before?

Comment: @JokasLokas Have a look at the project's [wiki](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/wiki). It describes how to install `gdx-facebook`. When you're done installing, take a look at the project's [example](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook-app). That should give you a basic understanding of how to use `gdx-facebook`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. that looks very useful. However, I have not installed roboVM, would you be able to direct me to a page which clearly explains how I can add that to my app first? :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a binding on the user interacting with the button which uses the API of the corresponding service to make a post. It's sufficiently complicated and there are so many ways of doing it that I don't suspect you'll find any one answer to this problem.

The basic part of reacting on a tap or a click will look something like this:

```
ClickListener shareFacebook = new ClickListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //Interacting with the facebook API here
    }
}

shareButton.addListener(shareFacebook)
```

In this example, the ClickListener is a **listener**-type object which will react to the following events happening: enter, exit, touchDown, touchDrag, and touchUp. The **binding** is the function which we define inside the listener. So if we define a function for touchDown, then whenever someone touches or clicks on the the entity we attach this to, the function we define there will run.

Similarly for the other events: enter on the mouse moving into the element's clickable region, exit on the mouse moving out of the element's clickable region, touchDrag on the mouse moving while being pressed, and touchUp on the mouse being released.

Comment: Thanks but i just said i do not know what binding is, that is what i need a tutorial on

Comment: So what this code does is it will run whatever code you put in the touchDown function when shareButton is clicked on/ tapped. The binding is just the concept of taking that function and -binding- it to the touchDown event. There are listeners which have a number of events they listen to, and you can define functions which occur on given events. Take a look at the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html) for specific usage questions. I'd be happy to answer specific questions as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the depth! however, I already understand that, the bit I dont understand is how to 'interact with the facebook API' on LibGDX.

Comment: which now i know, is the binding :)

Comment: It's a rather long process. You'll need to have the user login using the facebook API, get their permission to post, and then trigger some kind of post event. Facebook offers [tutorials](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/tutorials) on how to start working with their API. I imagine twitter has similar tools available.