# Convert LibGDX pixmap to Android bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, libgdx

I'm just trying to convert Pixmap to the Bitmap.
Here is how I'm creating the pixmap

```
screenShot = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture().getTexture().getTextureData().consumePixmap();
```

And that's how I'm trying to convert Pixmap to Bitmap.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(screenshot.getPixels().array(), 0, screenshot.getPixels().array().length);
```

But that's crashes on the second line I gave you there.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: why would you need to convert something from LibGDX to Android specific? LibGDX is cross-platform game development engine, hence you should avoid such kind of practice.

Comment: Cause I need to create a share button. And since I cannot do this in libgdx, I should just run platform specific code and create a new activity.

Comment: what kind of share button? have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32673189/5151575) ?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I need not only the Facebook sharing. With http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433/ this way I can access all the available share methods.

Comment: Save the pixmap to a PNG with PixmapIO. Twitter (and Facebook I think) just want an image file URI anyway; no need to load it as a bitmap yourself.

Comment: I thought about that. Then I will try to save the image and give an already created image path to my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I just didn't find the solution exactly to my answer.
But I've found another way to do what I needed. Thanks to Tenfour04.

I did the following steps:

1. Created the pixmap.
2. Saved that with PixmapIO.writePNG();
3. And linked that to the Android method.

This way it works for a custom static pixmap.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and fast

```
PNG writer = new PNG((int)(pixmap.getWidth() * pixmap.getHeight() * 1.5 f));
writer.setFlipY(false);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
 writer.write(output, pixmap);
} finally {
 StreamUtils.closeQuietly(output);
 writer.dispose();
 pixmap.dispose();
}
byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```